# Strict aliasing warning : typecasting uint64_t variable to a 64-bit sized structure

Tags: c, gcc, strict-aliasing

I am working on fixing the below problem in C-program on Linux (4.19.21-linux-gnu-gcc),

```
//Structure definition :

struct data_from_u64 {
uint32_t u32_value;
uint16_t u16_value;
uint8_t u8_value1;
uint8_t u8_value2;
}

//Expectation : Convert a incoming uint64_t variable to the above structure using the below macro, 

#define U64_TO_STRUCT(u64_value)  ( * (data_from_u64 *) ((void*)  &(u64_value)) )

//Usage
  data_from_u64 data = U64_TO_STRUCT(u64_value);
```

The project is huge that it is very widely used, but the new compilation procedure is enforcing "-O2" and "-Werror" flag while compiling. Can you help resolve the error/warning mentioned below. change should be minimal as this macro is used in more than 1000 places.

### Error/Warning:

error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
#define U64_TO_STRUCT(u64_value)  ( * (data_from_u64 *) ((void*)  &(u64_value)) )

### What have i tried :

I have tried doing memcpy, it works. But it requires to be updated in all the 1000places of usage[it requires parameter of the macro to be changed to include the destination].

Comment: You can change the macro to use memcpy (either by a gcc statement-expression, or an inline function)

Comment: @M.M : Thank you. I am working on an inline function based solution. will share the solution once i get succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
struct data_from_u64 U64_TO_STRUCT(uin64_t u64_value) {
    struct data_from_u64 ret;
    memcpy(&ret, &u64_value, sizeof u64_value);
    return ret;
}
```

It's a common misconception that you cannot return structs like this. You cannot return local arrays, but returning structs is perfectly fine.

And the lesson to learn from this, is that all nagging from us here at SO about "you're violating the anti aliasing rule" is not just some nerdy mumbojumbo that never matters in practice. As you can see for yourself, it does have real world consequences. :)

If you really want to have a macro for this, take a look at [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66332887/6699433) which works great, conforms to the standard and does not rely on compiler extensions. I personally just don't like function like macros.

Comment: @jeshmal4u Why not? This is valid C, and any system capable of running Linux should be able to return copy of 64-bit struct in stack.

Comment: @jeshmal4u You cannot do like this with arrays, but many thinks that you cannot do it with structs either. I was one of them in the past. Nevertheless, that code is perfectly valid.

Comment: What you can't do is returning a **pointer** to a local variable, but here the whole variable is returned.

Comment: @user694733 AFIK, there's no limit on how big the structs can be, provided you don't cause stack overflow or something. But there's no problem returning a struct of several kilobytes. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @klutt : I stand corrected. Your solution is valid. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @klutt C language doesn't specify limits. I don't know if Linux calling conventions do have additional limits, but I see no reason why it would.

Comment: @user694733 It sounded like you meant that returning 64-bit structs could cause problems on 32-bit systems.

Comment: @klutt I see. It was not intended that way.

Comment: Are there any compiler configurations which *correctly and reliably* handle all of the lvalue-access scenarios described by the Standard which would not treat usage pattern where a `T1*` is converted to `T2*` and *immediately* used to access storage which has also been accessed using `T1` in a manner consistent with the documented storage formats of the types in question?  The `-fstrict-aliasing` modes of clang and gcc won't handle the latter, but they sometimes behave in ways that may be a result of bugs, or bizarre interpretations of the Standard, but seem unlikely to ever be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to `memcpy` or the improper aliasing is to use a union with a compound literal:

```
#define U64_TO_STRUCT(u64_value) \
    ((union { uint64_t u; struct data_from_u64 s; }) { u64_value } .s)
```

Comment: This also works. Thank you so much for sharing your inputs.